# a problem with the skin of my cat

Tags: veterinarian

My cat had a fight with another cat about a month ago while he was in the street.
About a week ago the wound seems to close, but later on, this appeared at the site of the wound. It has been about 3 weeks since it started.
Can any one give me the diagnosis please? And how it can be treated?

[image: This is an image for the problem.]

Comment: My _guess_ would be a hot spot from infection, but I'd start by taking the cat to a vet rather than asking amateurs on the net

Comment: This is a good idea, but only if you have vets where you live!!
I do not know about any vet where I live.

Comment: You can call a vet far away and ask, if you could send a picture to them.

Comment: A good idea... I will try it